# How to access parent class function from derived class object in function over riding feature of C++

Tags: c++, function, oop, overriding

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
public: void getdata()
        {
            cout<<"in base"<<endl;
        }
};

class derived:public base
{
public: void getdata()
        {
            cout<<"in derived"<<endl;
        }
        void base:: getdata()
};

int main()
{
derived d;
d.getdata();
return 0;
}
```

I'm getting error: "cannot declare member function 'base::getdata' within 'derived'"

I want to print the content of both functions from derived class objects

Comment: FYI, using namespace std is a bad practice.

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `void base:: getdata()`?

Comment: You probably meant to do [this](https://godbolt.org/z/svoYnE) - Btw, nothing is _overridden_ here. `derived::getdata()` _hides_ `base::getdata()`.

Comment: `void base:: getdata()` You can't have two identical functions by the same name in the same scope.  But you can access both of them as `d.getdata();` and `d.base::getdata()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
public: 
  base() {

  }
  void getData()
  {
      cout << "in base" << endl;
  }

};

class derived :public base
{
public:

  derived(base b) {

      b.getData();
  }
  void getdata()
  {
      cout << "in derived" << endl;
  }

};

int main()
{
  base b;
  derived d(b);
  d.getdata();


 return 0;
}
```

**try this.**